# What is the most efficient searching algorithm to find the two values that are closest to the two values inputted by the user?

Tags: python, search

#The user inputs longitude and latitude represented by the variables "lon" and "lat" respectively. I want to search "mintemparr" to find the closest location to the input. My current algorithm goes through each value in the array to find the minimum difference in longitude and latitude which takes a very long time since the array is very large. Is there a more efficient algorithm to do this?

#One row of the "mintemparr" is in the format [longitude, latitude, temperature]. I am trying to find the temperature at the closest location to the input. My current algorithm traverses every row of this array.

```
def match (lon, lat):
    min=10000
    minindex=-1

    for x in range (len (mintemparr)):
        if (abs ((float (lon))-float (mintemparr [x][0])))+(abs ((float 
       (lat))-float (mintemparr [x][1])))<min:

              min=(abs ((float (lon))-float (mintemparr [x][0])))+(abs 
              ((float (lat))-float (mintemparr [x][1])))
              minindex=x

    result=mintemparr [minindex][2]
    print ("The Temperature is: ")
    print (result)

longitude=input ("Enter Longitude: ")
latitude=input ("Enter Latitude: ")
match (longitude, latitude)
```

#Sample input:

```
Enter Longitude: -140
Enter Latitude: 40
```

#Output:

```
The Temperature is -6.3244445
```

#The output is correct; it just takes a very long time.

#mintemparr is sorted such that the longitude increases from -180 to 180 while the latitude remains constant. Once at 180, latitude is incremented and the pattern continues.

#Portion of mintemparr:

```
-179.979166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.9375 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.895833333333343 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.854166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.8125 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.770833333333343 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
```

Comment: post the sample input and expected output

Comment: It is possible, but only under the constraint that mintemparray is sorted in some order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the value in the list, sort it, and take the values on the left and right of it. Here is an example:

```
lons=[float(i[0]) for i in mintemparr]

#check for nearest longtitude for lon:

lons.append(lon)
lons.sort()
mylon=lons[lons.index(lon)-1] if lon-lons[lons.index(lon)-1]< lons[lons.index(lon)+1]-lon else lons[lons.index(lon)+1]
```

the same for lats:

```
mintemparr_temp=[i for i in mintemparr if i[0]==mylon]
lats=[float(i[1]) for i in mintemparr_temp]

#check for nearest longtitude for lon:

lats.append(lat)
lats.sort()
mylat=lats[lats.index(lat)-1] if lat-lats[lats.index(lat)-1]< lats[lats.index(lat)+1]-lat else lats[lats.index(lat)+1]
```

And finally:

```
mytemp=[i for i in mintemparr if i[0]==mylon anf i[1]==mylat]
```

Comment: I had to change lons=[i[0] for i in mintemparr] and lats=[i[1] for i in mintemparr]
to  lons=[float (i[0]) for i in mintemparr] and lats=[float (i[1]) for i in mintemparr]. Other than that there are no errors. However, the output is [] when it should output a float. Another thing to note is that I am trying to find the closest value to the lon/lat input. There are no two values in mintemparr that exactly correspond to the input.Thanks for the response.

Comment: The output is just an empty array: "[]" I was expecting the ouput to be -6.3244445. There are no errors.

Comment: I have added one more line 
```mintemparr_temp=[i for i in mintemparr if i[0]==mylon]```
so that it will search for lat only in values that pair with the lon in mintemparr
Please try again and tell me if it works